# VBA Line Break Character

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to figure this out for over an hour. I am needing to insert a Line Break in my code. I know using a "_" can achieve this. Though I tried using this in the following code, it doesn't work. I am wanting to insert the line break between K68 & A69.
`"A67,F67,H67,K67,A68,K68,A69,F69,H69,K69,A70,K70,A71,F71,H71,K71,A72,K72`

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you are trying to write a long string.

**Try this**

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As String
    x = "A67,F67,H67,K67,A68,K68" _
    & ",A69,F69,H69,K69,A70,K70,A71,F71,H71,K71,A72,K7"
    MsgBox x
End Sub
```

**Update 1:**
Changed `+` to `&` and removed not needed parentheses based on GWD comment.

Comment: You should use `&` instead of `+` for string concatenation. Also, on the `MsgBox` call you should not use braces if you don't use the return value. Simply call it like this: `MsgBox x`.

Comment: Created an updated based on your comments. I've been programming in Java for way to long, and when I tried the `+` in vba it worked, and I forget that & is used in VBA :P

Comment: Sorry for the late response - had to get on several conference calls. I tried your suggestion and it worked perfectly. THANKS!